# rxjs BehavioralSubject for storing logged in user data in angular 12

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, behaviorsubject

I have header component, user posts component, commonModel service. When user login, I am trying to store user details in state using rxjs, so that in other components I will use that state. I am calling `fetchLoggedUserData` function in `getUserDetails` method when user login in and storing data using rxjs - `userData$` variable. Idea is whenever I need logged in user data, I need to use that with `userData$` variable so API does not get called every time. And when I need updated data then I can call  `fetchLoggedUserData` function again.

**commonModel service**

```
public userData$ = new BehaviorSubject(undefined);
 fetchLoggedUserData() {

      let userDetails = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser"));
    
      this.userService.getUserDetails(userDetails.id).subscribe((data) => {
        if (data["status"] === false) {
        } else {
       
          this.userData$.next(data["data"]);
        }
      });
  }
```

in **header component** after successful login I am calling `getUserDetails` method

```
 userDataSubscription$;

    getUserDetails() {
        console.log('here user in header');
        this.commonModelService.fetchLoggedUserData();
        this.userDataSubscription$ = this.commonModelService.userData$.subscribe(
          (data) => {
            if (data !== undefined) {
              console.log('logged in user data from header', data);
            }
          }
        );

    ngOnDestroy() {
        
       if(this.userDataSubscription$){
         this.userDataSubscription$.unsubscribe();
       }
        
      }
```

**user-posts component**

```
userDataSubscription$;

getUserDetails() {
    console.log('here user in posts ');
    this.userDataSubscription$ = this.commonModelService.userData$.subscribe(
      (data) => {
        if (data !== undefined) {
          console.log('logged in user data from posts', data);
          
        }
      }
    );
}
 
ngOnDestroy() {
        
       if(this.userDataSubscription$){
         this.userDataSubscription$.unsubscribe();
       }
        
      }
```

With first time login it shows correct results. But when I logout and login again, it shows repeated values.
First time login

[image]

second time login

[image]

I have tried to resolve it by adding `pipe with takeuntill` but it did not work.

```
 export function componentDestroyed(component: OnDestroy) {
      const oldNgOnDestroy = component.ngOnDestroy;
      const destroyed$ = new ReplaySubject<void>(1);
      component.ngOnDestroy = () => {
        oldNgOnDestroy.apply(component);
        destroyed$.next(undefined);
        destroyed$.complete();
      };
      return destroyed$.asObservable();
    }
    
      getUserDetails() {
        console.log('here user in posts ');
        this.userDataSubscription$ = this.commonModelService.userData$.pipe(takeUntil(componentDestroyed(this))).subscribe(
          (data) => {
            if (data !== undefined) {
              console.log('logged in user data from posts', data);
            }
          }
        );
    
     ngOnDestroy() {
        
        // if(this.userDataSubscription$){
        //   this.userDataSubscription$.unsubscribe();
        // }
        
      }
```

My questions are

1. Is above way right to store or get updated user data and access it in multiple components so that API call will get reduced?
2. How I can avoid that repeated values even if same user logins multiple time or different user logins?

Please guide and help. Thanks.

Comment: This is probably because you are subscribing directly to behaviour subject. Create a function that returns `return userData$.asObservable()` and try subscribing to that, observable emmited by behaviour subject only emmits last value. On logout dont forget to unsubscribe from every observable  and nulify behaviourSubject like `userData$.next(null)`

Comment: @tony I tried your suggestion but it did not work. on logout if write `userData$.next(null)` then it gives error `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'first_name')` as in userdata i had user data. and by creating function which will return observable still shows repeated values.

Comment: This is kind of complicated to debug, try setting up a stackblitz project

Comment: Do your components get actually destroyed as you expect? Looks to me like they dont. Try adding a log in your destroy hook. If im not sure if there are more components at play than i would expect, I add some instance specific and random Attribute to it and log that as well, such as math.random() or whatever.